# The error in getting the exact value from the XML node when the '\' value is in string and that string in passed used as xml instead of file

Tags: c#

I am having XML in a String as below

```
String s = @<user>abc.int\abhi</user>
```

but when i write the following code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.InnerXml = s;
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
 String User  = root.SelectSingleNode("user");
```

The User has the value `abc.int\\abhi` instead of `abc.int\abhi` the '\' character appears twice in the string.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you check that value in VS watch window? If so, it is normal to display \, because watch window shows string as if it was written in code, not the real string.
In code, if you want to enter \ into a string, you have to write `string s = "\\";` And this will create actual string with \ in it.
try outputting your string to console or messagebox, and you should see, that it is correct.

Comment: When i watched the string s in add watch the string that comes is abc.int\\abhi i dont want that extra \ in the string i want the string as  abc.int\abhi

Comment: Again, how do you check, that your string have \\ in it? Please to show this string in `MessageBox.Show(str)` and check again if you still see \\.

Comment: yeah i see the \\ in the string i saw in in add watch. consider i have a string String s = abc.int\\abhi i want to remove single '\' character from the string S and make it abc.int\abhi

Comment: Ok then, you confirm my first guess. This string is OK, it has only only \, not \\! It is just VS, that show \\ in watch window. Third time I ask you: execute `MessageBox.Show(str)` with your string, and you should see that it has one \.

Comment: Sorry dear i should have chkecked before posting it here got the answer its workin fine.. thank you..